# Label elements in a duplicate list

Tags: python, list

Is there any good way to do this:

```
    input  = ['hi you', 'hello', 'hi you', 'hello', 'good bye']
    output = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

Many thanks!!

( I just edited the input list. Instead of alphabet list my case actually is the new list)

Comment: `output = [ord(x) for x in input]` does it give what you want? What do 1, 2, and 3 suppose to mean? Alphabet index, index of first occurrence, or any arbitrary identifier?

Comment: what if this isn't the alphabet input list but a list of string? and 1, 2, 3 are just the appearance order of each string

Comment: In this case, I would go with the solution of the deleted answer posted minutes ago here. I wish the writer comes back and rewrites his answer.

Comment: Also, I recommend you to explain your question clearly and avoid generalizations which will lead to non proper answers like we have here.

Comment: @AliTou That answer did not match the given input and output since he wishes to replace `c` with 3 despite it only appearing at the end of the list

Comment: hi @mousetail, what about this list ['hi you', 'hello', hi you', 'hello', 'good bye'] ?

Comment: @LeVuMinhHuy Can you please edit y our anser with the expected results from both strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it like this:

```
output = [input.index(i) for i in input]
```

Every value in output will be the first index of the value at that index in input. If you want arrays to start at one use:

```
output = [input.index(i) + 1 for i in input]
```

(Though you probably want to avoid using built-in functions like input for variable names)

Answer (score 1):

The `ord()` function gives the unicode value of a character. For example, `ord('a') == 97`.

In unicode, as well as most other character encoding, normal letters are stored in order. Thus, you can get the index of any other letter by simply subtracting `ord('a')`, for example: `ord('b') - ord('a') == 1` and `ord('z') - ord('a') == 25`. Of course you can add one to get a 1 based index.

Using this knowledge, we can build a comprehension that does what you want:

```
output = [ord(i) - ord('a') + 1 for i in input]
```

This will give the desired results for your example input. However, if your string contains any capital letters or simbols, results might be strange. For example `ord('A') == 65` so if your string contains a capital `A` it will be replaced by `-31`. If you want to treat capital letters the same use:

```
output = [ord(i.lower()) - ord('a') + 1 for i in input]
```

Answer (score 1):

The most time efficient way would be to build a mapping from the values to the first encountered index:

```
>>> data = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c']
>>> index = {}
>>> for x in data:
...     if x not in index:
...         index[x] = len(index) + 1
...
>>> index
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Then simply map the original data:

```
>>> [index[x] for x in data]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done this way:

```
idx_dict, result, counter = {}, [], 1 #idx_dict stores first index of every unique value
for i in input1:
    if i not in idx_dict: #stores the first index of every unique value in idx_dict 
        idx_dict[i] = counter
        counter += 1
    result.append(idx_dict[i]) #for every value encountered get its first index from the idx_dict and append to result list
```

This basically solves the problem in 'n' iterations